# boost asio `async_write` not generating broken pipe or other error on disconnected client even after a `FIN` has been received from server

Tags: c++, tcp, boost-asio, unix-socket

Hello I'm having a problem with a basic tcp server/client.

Client code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include "chat_message.hpp"

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

typedef std::deque<chat_message> chat_message_queue;

class chat_client
{
public:
    chat_client(boost::asio::io_context& io_context,
                const tcp::resolver::results_type& endpoints)
        : io_context_(io_context),
        socket_(io_context),
        worker_{std::make_shared<boost::asio::io_service::work>(io_context)}
    {
        do_connect(endpoints);
    }

    void write(const chat_message& msg)
    {
        std::cerr << "write" << std::endl;
        do_write(msg);
    }

    void close()
    {
        std::cout << "boost::asio::post close" << std::endl;
        boost::asio::post(io_context_, [this]() {
            std::cout << "socket.close" << std::endl;
           socket_.close();
        });
    }

private:
    void do_connect(const tcp::resolver::results_type& endpoints)
    {
        boost::asio::async_connect(socket_, endpoints,
                                   [this](boost::system::error_code ec, tcp::endpoint)
                                   {
                                       if (ec)
                                       {
                                           std::cerr << __LINE__ << " | connect handler " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                                       }
                                   });
    }

    void do_read_header()
    {
        std::cout << "do_read_header" << std::endl;
        boost::asio::async_read(socket_,
                                boost::asio::buffer(read_msg_.data(), chat_message::header_length),
                                [this](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
                                {
                                    std::cout << "do_read_header callback" << std::endl;
                                    if (!ec && read_msg_.decode_header())
                                    {
                                        do_read_body();
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        std::cerr << __LINE__ << " | header read handler " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                                        socket_.close();
                                    }
                                });
    }

    void do_read_body()
    {
        boost::asio::async_read(socket_,
                                boost::asio::buffer(read_msg_.body(), read_msg_.body_length()),
                                [this](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
                                {
                                    if (!ec)
                                    {
                                        std::cout.write(read_msg_.body(), read_msg_.body_length());
                                        std::cout << "\n";
                                        // do_read_header();
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        std::cerr << __LINE__ << " | body read handler" << ec.message() << std::endl;
                                        // socket_.close();
                                    }
                                });
    }

    void do_write(const chat_message& msg)
    {
        boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
                                 boost::asio::buffer(msg.data(), msg.length()),
                                 [this](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length)
                                 {
                                     std::cerr << __LINE__ << " | write handler " << ec.message() << "-" << length << std::endl;
                                     if (!ec)
                                     {
                                         do_read_header();
                                     }
                                 });
    }

private:
    boost::asio::io_context& io_context_;
    tcp::socket socket_;
    std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> worker_;
    chat_message read_msg_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        if (argc != 3)
        {
            std::cerr << "Usage: chat_client <host> <port>\n";
            return 1;
        }

        boost::asio::io_context io_context;
        auto work = std::make_shared<boost::asio::io_service::work>(io_context);

        tcp::resolver resolver(io_context);
        auto endpoints = resolver.resolve(argv[1], argv[2]);
        chat_client c(io_context, endpoints);

        std::thread t([&io_context](){ io_context.run(); });

        char line[chat_message::max_body_length + 1];
        while (std::cin.getline(line, chat_message::max_body_length + 1))
        {
            chat_message msg;
            msg.body_length(std::strlen(line));
            std::memcpy(msg.body(), line, msg.body_length());
            msg.encode_header();
            c.write(msg);
        }

        c.close();
        t.join();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Server code https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/chat/chat_server.cpp

Steps to reproduce:

- Run the server
- Run the client (it will make a tcp connection)
- Stop the server (SIGTERM/Ctrl+C)
- Write something in client cli and hit Enter (it will send the msg to server, that is already stooped)

Current behavior:
[image]

Sniffer trace:
[image: FIN command from server]
[image: FIN_ACK from client]
[image: Send msg from client]
[image: RST as msg request response]

My questions:

- If the server is sending a `RST` as response to write message, why `boost::asio` is reporting Success in the write callback? is this the expected behavior?
- Should I detect connection problems in read operation or is it possible to detect it in write (I think so because tcp open an stream and ACK for each operation should be received)?

Comment: FIN only means the peer has finished sending. It doesn't imply that he has finished receiving. Ergo no RST.

Comment: @user207421 after some relevant time the write operation give me back a broken pipe error, but it takes some time.

Comment: That's normal. You can't expect the reset straight away.